# how to check payload size in scripting component in mule 3

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-component

I'm trying to check the size of payload in **scripting component** in **mule 3** but it's not working and getting script error. Please suggest the correct code.

```
 if(sizeOf (payload) > 0){
   flowVars.username = "aaaaaaaaa"
 }
 else{
   flowVars.username = "bbbbbb"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mule 3 you need to be aware of the Java class used to implement the payload. If it is a String you can use the method `length()` (ie `payload.length()`. If it is a collection use `size()`. Some classes or interfaces don't have an actual size.

The function `sizeOf()` seems to be the Mule 3 DataWeave operator, which will not work in Mule 3 expressions or the scripting component. If you need to understand the language that you are using.